# How to call object in array from it's name

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have this array `categories = [Sports, Kids]`

Where `Sports` and `Kids` are not strings, they're objects imported after `export const Sports = {...}` export from another file.

I Have also `categoriesLoop = ['Sports', 'Kids']` to loop over the categories in `<select>` to do this: `categoriesLoop.map(category => <option>{category}</option>` in react.

Now the question how to access the `Sports` and `Kids` **objects** from their **string names** within their array - `categories` - ?

Like, When I do this in my select `onChange`:

```
const category = e.currentTarget.value;
console.log(categories[category]);
```

I get **undefined**, Because the string 'Sports' not exists in the `categories` which has an **objects** not **strings**.

**How to get that `Sports` object in `categories` When I have the string `'Sports'`?**

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try: `categories[categoriesLoop.indexOf(category)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an object instead of an array, and then just use bracket notation:

```
const categories = { Sports, Kids };
// ...
const category = e.currentTarget.value;
console.log(categories[category]);
```

Capitalization matters - here, you'd have to input `Sports` exactly, or `Kids` exactly. Since this sounds like it's from user input, you might consider using lower-cased keys, and then `trim`ming and lower-casing the input value:

```
const categories = { sports: Sports, kids: Kids };
// ...
const category = e.currentTarget.value.trim().toLowerCase();
console.log(categories[category]);
```